# Which jQuery method could you use to view or change the html for an id called header?

Tags: jquery

I do not know if it is either `$("#header").val();` or `$("#header").html();`. Can someone please tell me the difference as well? I tried looking at the jquery websties and other websites but they only confused me further.

Comment: what is the control your are trying to access. is it a div or span or any other,

Comment: I want to view the html of the id header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html():

```
Obtains the HTML content of the first element in the matched set.
$('#Container').html()
```

text()

Concatenates all text content of the wrapped elements and returns it as the result of the method. That means this method return all the string which display on our browser.

```
$('#Container').text()
```

val()

Returns the value attribute of the first element in the matched set. When the element is a multiselect element, the returned value is an array of all selections. This method only work with control like input, select, button etc. It not work with div, span, p etc.

```
$('#txtCountry').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, if you use `.html()` the actual html elements including the text within them are returned.  `.val()` will return only the text within those tags.

`.html()` is useful for when you want to move or alter the actual html.
`.val()` is mainly used to get the value of an `<input>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the html just use this line:

```
$("#header").html()
```

that will return the html inside the id.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between `val`, `html` and `text` in jquery:

```
html()
```

Obtains the `HTML` content of the first element in the matched set.

```
$('#Container').html()

text()
```

Concatenates all text content of the wrapped elements and returns it as the result of the method. That means this method return all the string which display on our browser.

```
$('#Container').text()

val()
```

Returns the value attribute of the first element in the matched set. When the element is a multiselect element, the returned value is an array of all selections. This method only work with control like input, select, button etc. It not work with `div`, `span`, `p` etc.

```
$('#txtCountry').val()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jQuery With Example</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $("#btnClick").click(function () {
        alert("HTML: " + $("#Container").html());
        alert("Text: " + $("#Container").text());
        alert("Value: " + $("#txtCountry").val());
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Container">
    <b>Country</b>
    <input type="text" id="txtCountry" value="India" />
  </div>
  <button id="btnClick">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```